# How can I change the range of countif() inside an arrayformula()?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting, countif

I want to find duplicates that happen after the current row.  I can find duplicates that happen anywhere with this formula but I don't want to flag the last occurrence of a particular value as being a duplicate.

`=arrayformula(if(row(B:B) = 1, "Duplicate", if(not(isblank(A:A)), if(countif(A:A, A:A) > 1, "Yes", "No"), "")))`

If I statically specify a starting cell in the lookup range it only finds duplicates after that spot. However I need to have the starting spot change based on the row I'm on.

`=arrayformula(if(row(B:B) = 1, "Duplicate", if(not(isblank(A:A)), if(countif(A5:A, A:A) > 1, "Yes", "No"), "")))`

I tried using indirect() and row() but it doesn't seem to update for each row.

`=arrayformula(if(row(B:B) = 1, "Duplicate", if(not(isblank(A:A)), if(countif(indirect("A"&row(B:B)&":A"), A:A) > 1, "Yes", "No"), "")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={"Duplicate"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()+1&":A")<>"", 
 IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()+1&":A"), INDIRECT("A"&ROW()+1&":A")) > 1, "Yes", "No"), ))}
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

```
={"Duplicate"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,
 IF(COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), ">="&ROW(A2:A))>1, "Yes", "No")))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I get #REF! result was not automatically expanded, please insert more rows

Comment: It stopped filling the whole sheet but isn't calculating correctly, I'm playing with it to see if I can make it work.  Is the +1 because everything is shifted by putting the header first in the array braces?

Comment: @Mike yes for +1

Comment: The last three should not be listed as a duplicate but the first 3 should be.  Duplicate might be the wrong word, I'm trying to exclude (mark as duplicate) all but the most recent instance of a given value.

Comment: can you provide example of desired output in your sheet?

Comment: I added it to the sheet I linked in the question in column C.  It works if I do the formula manually in each cell